# jquery block ui getting $.blockUI is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this very simple script of jQuery plugin called [blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview)
I found many posts with the same issue but no resolution
Can someone take a look at this snippet or suggest an alternative to blockUI?
Thank you!

```js
function block() {
alert('gonna block')
  $.blockUI();
  setTimeout(unBlock(), 5000); 
}

function unBlock() {
 $.unblockUI();
}

function alertUser() {  
  alert('Alert User'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

<button onclick="alertUser()">Alert</button>
<button onclick="block()">Block!</button>
<button onclick="unBlock()">UnBlock!</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work but you are calling unblock instantly and it goes away, pass the function into setTimeout instead of calling it.

```js
function block() {
  $.blockUI();
  setTimeout(unBlock, 5000); 
}

function unBlock() {
  $.unblockUI();
}

function alertUser() {  
  alert('Alert User'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

<button onclick="alertUser()">Alert</button>
<button onclick="block()">Block!</button>
<button onclick="unBlock()">UnBlock!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery before you include any plugins.

Change the order of your includes.